# Why can one assume in "infinite grid of resistors" that in the center there are diagonal nodes that have $-1$ and $+1$ currents?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Why can one assume in "infinite grid of resistors" that in the center there are diagonal nodes that have $-1$ and $+1$ currents?

As in the matrix $P$ in the following picture:

[image: resis]

Comment: Were you asked to find the equivalent resistance between those particular nodes?

Comment: @ThePhoton, further down the line, yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

In comments you said you were asked to find the equivalent resistance between these nodes.

Imagine you had a physical resistor network and were asked to measure the equivalent resistance between two nodes of that network. One way to do that would be to apply a test current in one of those nodes and out the other, and measure the voltage developed between the nodes.

What your book is showing is mathematically modeling what would happen if that test were done on the infinite network of resistors.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You asked why you can assume a current going in one node and out the other. My answer says you can assume a current going in one node and out the other because you could test the network by applying such a current.

Comment: So you say that it doesn't matter which two nodes we measure, for the resistance that is?

Comment: It should be the two nodes you were asked to find the equivalent resistance between.

Comment: why are they -1 and +1 then?

Comment: "why are they -1 and +1 then?" -- if you were to apply a voltmeter across those two nodes, a current flows thru the voltmeter as the means of measuring the voltage across the nodes.  The current flow has direction.  The + node would be current leaving the node to flow thru the voltmeter.  The - node is the same current flowing back into the network so its direction is obviously opposite of the first + node.

Comment: @K7PEH, an ideal voltmeter doesn't allow any current to pass through it. This "experiment" would involve a current source with a voltmeter in parallel to it.

Comment: @mavavilj, they're +1 and -1 because the current from your test source flows into the network at one node and out at the other.

Comment: @ThePhoton But why are they located there?